# File Encoding - What kind of encoding is this?

Tags: css, character-encoding, intellij-idea

I recently compiled project with maven 3.1. Just after that source codes turned into this.

����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

It's sample of CSS file. I'm using IntelliJ 13.

How to turn this into human readable format?

Comment: `human readable format` As opposed to what? Klingon?

Comment: That'a a unicode "unknown glyph". we can't help you with that. "here's a bunch of black boxes. tell me what's inside them".

Comment: Looks like file corruption to me. Time to go to the backup. You do back up, don't you?

Comment: It was nice of you to post the exact number of unknown glyphs as opposed to just saying "There are a whole lot of �"

Comment: IntelliJ tells you what encoding it's trying to display the file as. Look at the bottom-right toolbar, where your heap memory bar, inspection indicator, read-only attribute control, source control, and other items are. You can click on it to select different encoding types. You might try switching encodings, but I'm not sure that's going to help much.

Comment: @Floris - I don't have any backup. I was compiling it with local drive.

Comment: @MarcB - It's a code of CSS file. It happened to all source codes including java and XML files.I just copied and pasted it from source.

Comment: doesn't matter what it is. you get that glyph if the particular character encoded in that point is unknown to the font you're trying to display it in. it's like the broken image icon you get in a browser. It could be a picture of a elephant, or a cpu, or the latest pneumatically enhanced centerfold - there's no way to know, because it's a GENERIC icon, not an image.

Comment: @ajp15243 - When I try to convert file encoding with UTF16 or UTF8, it says me - "Valid Token Expected" and turned same code into this -
 
??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

What to do now?

Comment: do a binary dump of the file contents to see if anything legible is still in there.

Comment: The symbol “�” is REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, indicating data that does not constitute a valid representation of *any* character. So you really need to open the file in a program that lets you see the data in binary or hexadecimal, without trying to interpret it as characters.

Comment: @Floris - I don't know how to do that. Will you please guide me with it?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - If I open whole project's files in binary or hexadecimal base format, Will I get back original source? Because as you see there will be only 0,1 or 0-F values.

Comment: What kind of machine do you have? Windows, Mac, Linux,... Let me know so I can guide you with binary dump. Or put the file on Dropbox with a link here so people can look at it / try some things.

Comment: @Floris : I'm using Windows. Unfortunately, I deleted whole project because of frustration and now I'm unable to provide files for you to help me. It's the only left over in description content of question. Is it still possible for you to guide me with binary dumps? It'll be a great help.

Comment: Take a look at the answer given at http://superuser.com/a/468466 . The tool it recommends allows you to look at the binary (hex) representation of file contents, alongside any characters that might still be readable. Probably would give you a lot of insights. Sorry it cannot help you this time. Continuous automatic backup (for Windows, look at Mozy: http://mozy.com/product/mozy/personal ) is the other thing you should really consider investing in. $5.99 a month should have you pretty well covered (50G). Then these glitches (which happen to all of us) will be less of a disaster in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my last comment a little bit - I copied the text of your question into a text editor and saved it. Then I viewed it with the Mac/Linux command `od -cx` which prints both the character, and the hex representation, when possible. For your question the first few lines gave:

```
od -cx junk.txt 
0000000    I       r   e   c   e   n   t   l   y       c   o   m   p   i
             2049    6572    6563    746e    796c    6320    6d6f    6970
0000020    l   e   d       p   r   o   j   e   c   t       w   i   t   h
             656c    2064    7270    6a6f    6365    2074    6977    6874
0000040        m   a   v   e   n       3   .   1   .       J   u   s   t
             6d20    7661    6e65    3320    312e    202e    754a    7473
0000060        a   f   t   e   r       t   h   a   t       s   o   u   r
             6120    7466    7265    7420    6168    2074    6f73    7275
0000100    c   e       c   o   d   e   s       t   u   r   n   e   d    
             6563    6320    646f    7365    7420    7275    656e    2064
0000120    i   n   t   o       t   h   i   s   .  \n  \n  \n   �  **  **
             6e69    6f74    7420    6968    2e73    0a0a    ef0a    bdbf
0000140    �  **  **   �  **  **   �  **  **   �  **  **   �  **  **   �
             bfef    efbd    bdbf    bfef    efbd    bdbf    bfef    efbd
```

As you can see, the bytes are swapped (the first two bytes in the file are `0x49 0x20` representing "I space", but they are shown "backwards" (little endian representation). The same thing can be see with the rest of the "readable" characters; when you get to the "unreadable" characters, you find they are (in correct sequence) comprised of the bytes

```
0xef 0xbf 0xbd
```

repeated over and over again.  This is the "universal replacement characters" (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/4391782/1967396 or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29) - used to represent a character that could not be shown (and it becomes the question-mark-in-a-diamond when displayed). Presumably, the multiple copy/paste operations from your original file to Stack Overflow caused this substitution. Looking at the original file with a binary dump I am guessing you would have seen a different character representation; maybe you could have done something with it, but maybe it is just the way that Maven squelched your file.